# Can i store and retrieve ag grid column state, filter view?

Tags: angularjs, gridview, datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

We are currently using DevExtreme Data Grid for our Angular 1.x application and we allow user to save their preferred column view and filter views and retrieve them later after logout and login.

Does ag Grid allow the same feature of saving the grid view on the database?

I have researched on the internet for this, many people recommended using setMethod and getMethod and store on the local storage.

Does any one tried to store the grid column view and filter view in the database and retrieved back?

Our technology stack is Angular 1.x,JavaSpring, Oracle

Comment: Yes, this is very easily achievable in ag-Grid. Take a look at the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-definitions/#column-api-example).

Comment: @Viqas Thank you so much !